# S3 command not working in cron

Tags: ubuntu, cron, crontab, cronjob

I have this ultra simple cron job:

```
48 20 * * * cd /home/pankaj;s3cmd -f get s3://myfile.gz
```

The command works by itself. But the cron job does not. The cron job
is created for the same user(pankaj) who is able to run the command.
There is not much information in /var/log/syslog either.

```
Oct 15 20:48:01 dev CRON[17020]: (pankaj) CMD (cd /home/pankaj;s3cmd -f get s3://myfile.gz)
Oct 15 20:48:01 dev CRON[17019]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)
```

How can I find out what is going wrong?
The permissions of .s3cfg are like these:

```
pankaj@dev:~$ ls -l .s3cfg 
-rw------- 1 pankaj pankaj 2050 Feb  7  2018 .s3cfg
```

Comment: The first step would be to get a look at the output! Try installing a mail server, or redirecting stdout/stderr. Have you tried running the command without a PTY?

Comment: Where you have this `s3cmd` script? Try to use absolute path to this script and add option to point to the config file ;) I think you setup this cron job on root account but `.s3cfg` file is in `pankaj` HOMEDIR.

Comment: Thanks Attie and mariaczi. Your hints helped

Answer (score 0):

Modified the cronjob to this:

```
48 20 * * * cd /home/pankaj;s3cmd -f get s3://myfile.gz 2>&1 | tee log
```

And log showed this:

```
s3cmd: command not found
```

:(. So a simple change solved the problem:

```
48 20 * * * cd /home/pankaj;/usr/local/bin/s3cmd -f get s3://myfile.gz
```